# Which is more suitable for professional design Bootstrap or Foundation?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi i am going to develop a professional website.
I wanted to know which css will be more suitable for designing purposes? 
Bootstrap 3 or Foundation 5?

or is there any other css i can go for?

Comment: It depends. It might be neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on taste and use case. Bootstrap is able to provide good results verry fast. But you are bound to many parts of it. Foundation is able to give you a more general Framework. From what I know, both systems have problems with older internet explorers. But foundation maybe has some more Problems with that. Most companys I know, use Bootstrap. However, everyone has to adjust and customize the files for their fitting.

I use Boostrap because it works perfectly for my CMS (typo3).

Comment: A lot of bootstrap sites tend to look pretty similar but it doesn't have to be that way. You can use as much or as little as you want and you can easily override styles to give a more custom look. Basically it gives you a great starting point.

Comment: This is why i mentioned that you need to customize. In my opinion the first steps are fast and decent in quality. Customizing is not that hard as a Task, but foundation seems to provide a more general approach directly. This is why you may wanna choose that, it depends on your skills and needs.